# simple url rewriting using htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite

```
website.com/feed/file.xml
```

to

```
website.com/feed
```

using htaccess?

I need the user to access first line and show him the content from 2'nd line.

***Edit 1:** posted current .htaccess*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule    ^feed?$    feed/sejururi.xml    [NC,L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: any other thoughts here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `I need the user to access first line and show him the content from 2'nd line.`

This rule should for you in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteRule ^(feed)/sejururi\.xml$ /$1 [NC,L]
```

#### UPDATE: Full .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(feed)/sejururi\.xml$ $1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: for some reason it gives a 404

Comment: yes here it is http://www.gtsturism.ro/feed/sejururi.xml however http://www.gtsturism.ro/feed/ works.

Comment: Also are your sure .htaccess and mod_rewrite are enabled?

Comment: yes it is enabled since it is wp and custom url works. please see edit 1

Comment: Ok got it, problem is ordering of rule. You need to place my suggested rule before WP rules. See my edited answer.

Comment: Hi I want to know that through .htaccess file I can rewrite the code like www.hello.com/#page/ to www.hello.com/page/ so that the URL become shareable

Comment: @programmer: No hash tags are managed and processed by browsers itself and web server only gets `www.hello.com/` URL.

Comment: But my whole project is using the # tags (history classes) to go to another class but as you said the # is not understood by the browser so how can i make my url sharable so that google can read that

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule    ^feed?$    feed/file.xml    [NC,L]
```